C++ compilers have issue with template arguments in macro expansion
I tested against g++ and clang++ and have derived a MWE after experiencing this earlier today while writing some unit tests:
#define EXPECT_EQ(A, B)

template <typename A, typename B>
class C {
public:
  static bool foo() { return true; }
};

class A { };
class B { };
int main() {
  EXPECT_EQ(C<A, B>::foo(), true);
}

The compiler error is too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation or a more descriptive macro "EXPECT_EQ" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2.
Is this the expected behavior? I noted I had to resolve this issue by simply calling foo() prior to the macro.

Macros don't recognize <> so you have an extra comma.

Why do you even write a MACRO for this? You should only use macros when you really need pre-processor text expansion. In this case in C++ you should use a function template. e.g. something like this  template <typename type_t> constexpr bool EXPECT_EQ(T&& lhs, T&& rhs) { return lhs == rhs; }.  Side note in your example also considert foo to be constexpr (because it can be evaluated at compile time)

@PepijnKramer The macro looks like it came from GoogleTest.

@PasserBy I think you're right :)

" I had to resolve this issue by simply calling foo() prior to the macro." Another way is to use extra parenthesis: EXPECT_EQ((C<A, B>::foo()), true);.

Macros are handled by the preprocessor before the compiler is run. The preprocessor doesn't recognize complex C++ language syntaxes, like templates. Macro arguments are delimited strictly on commas, so the statement:
EXPECT_EQ(C<A, B>::foo(), true);
Is interpreted by the preprocessor as having 3 arguments passed in:
C<A
B>::foo()
true
Hence the "too many arguments provided" error, and why calling foo() before the macro invocation solves the problem.
